# Converting a XML UTF-8 to ANSI with xmloutputter

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, jdom

I have written a xml file in java using the xmloutputter. The standard format is UTF-8. Now I want to change it to ANSI.. How do I do that?

My code:

```
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File(Fileoutputpfad)));
```

Why can't I just change the `Format.getPrettyFormat()` into `Format.setEncoding()`?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Format.setEncoding()` is not a static method.

You can do this:

```
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat().setEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```